# React Navigation Spread Operator

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am working with React Navigation and the following example was provided for navigation options.  I have no idea what the spread operator is doing here...

```
class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: (navigation, defaultHeader) => ({
      ...defaultHeader,
      visible: true,
     }),
   }
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object spread operator (which is different to the array spread operator)lets you copy enumerable properties from one object to another.

```
{
    ...defaultHeader,
      visible: true,
},
```

is creating a new object first copying the values from the defaultHeader object and then adding the attribute "visible" to the new object.

By using arrow function we avoid having to type the function keyword, return keyword (it’s implicit in arrow functions), and curly brackets.

So basiclly the header attribute in this case refers to the a function which takes two arguements and returns a object (note as stated with fat arrow syntax we dont have to explicity add the return statement).